# Some attributes not changing but others are

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made code that changes the header opacity when scrolling down, but I want it to change the background colour when it scrolls down. Not sure why but it does not change this attribute, but changes the other attributes (like opacity and transition duration). Why is it not changing the background colour?

The code input demo has a display error when uploading to this site but not sure why as it works fine on my website:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
});
</script>
```

```css
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.7;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1.0s;
 background:#777a7c;
}
```

Comment: Try using this `background:#777a7c !important;`.

Comment: Or just do `#header-wrap.scroll-opacity-change`instead of using `!important`

Comment: !important should never be the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the css property rules are applied based on the specificity.

Read : http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

**An id is more specific than a class is more specific than an element.**

Due to this the background property from the id class is getting applied, you will have to either make background property  in class **!important** (Importance has precedence over specificity) or  use the **#header-wrap.scroll-opacity-change**

```js
var headerWrap = $('#header-wrap');
$(window).scroll(function() {
    headerWrap.addClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    if($(this).scrollTop() === 0) {
        headerWrap.removeClass('scroll-opacity-change');
    }
});
```

```css
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;/* may not be needed but no harm in having */
 z-index:100000;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
#header-wrap.scroll-opacity-change{
 opacity:0.7;
    background:#000;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 1.0s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 1.0s;
 
}

body
{
  height:1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-wrap">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem. The id selector has a hight specificity than the class selector. So you need to make the class selector have a higher specificity. You can do that by adding the id to the selector.

Change

```
.scroll-opacity-change{
```

to

```
#header-wrap.scroll-opacity-change {
```